# How to move this span to the left in dropdown button?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a dropdown button that contains a span which is kind of label. The point is that I use specific width which is needed, but Whatever I tried span is not moving to the left. it still stays in the center.

```html
<dropdown-button class="dropdown-button">
    <span class="dropdown-label">Select it</span>
<dropdown-button>
```

```css
.dropdown-button {
      min-width: 160px;
      font-size: 14px;}

.dropdown-label {
        text-align: left;}
```

How can I move that dropdown-label which is a span element to the left of the button?

Comment: plz can you add your html

Comment: I've updated HTML hierarchy  for making it more clear

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. You can see updated question

Comment: have you tried to float it left?

Answer (score 1):

Text-align needs to be set in the button element, not the span child element.

```css
button {
      min-width: 160px;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: left;}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>Select it</span>
</button>
```